# Azure Data Factory ForEachActivity: @item() evaluating to an empty string in .NET SDK

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk-.net

I am programmatically creating an Azure Data Factory pipeline using the .NET SDK. I'm trying to use the ForEachActivity and within it, I reference  `@item()` in the DatasetReference. However, it seems that `@item()` is evaluating to an empty string. Below is the code snippet that demonstrates the creation of the `ForEachActivity` and the subsequent pipeline:

```cs
ForEachActivity forEachActivity = new ForEachActivity
{
    Name = "ForEachDbContainer",
    BatchCount = 20,  // You can adjust this based on your needs
    //IsSequential = false,
    Items = new Expression { Value = "@array(['Source_db1_container1'])" },
    Activities = new List<Activity>
    {
        new CopyActivity
        {
            Name = "CosmosDBCopyActivity",
            Inputs = new List<DatasetReference> { new DatasetReference { ReferenceName = "@item()" } },
            Outputs = new List<DatasetReference> { new DatasetReference { ReferenceName = "Destination_db1_container1" } },
            Source = new DocumentDbCollectionSource { },
            Sink = new DocumentDbCollectionSink { },
        }
    }
};

PipelineResource pipeline = new PipelineResource
{
    Activities = new List<Activity> { forEachActivity }
};
client.Pipelines.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, "YourPipelineName", pipeline);
```

When executing the above code, I'm facing the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The document creation or update failed because of invalid reference ''.
```

Can anyone help me figure out why @item() is evaluating to an empty string, and how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are experiencing could be related to the way you are using the `@item()` expression in the `DatasetReference` object.

The `@item()` expression is used to reference the current item in the `Items` array of the `ForEachActivity`. However, in your code, you are using the `@item()` expression as the `ReferenceName` of the `DatasetReference` object, which is not correct.

You should use the below code to create for each activity like:

```cs
ForEachActivity forEachActivity = new ForEachActivity
{
    Name = "ForEachDbContainer",
    BatchCount = 20, 
    //IsSequential = false,
    Items = new Expression { Value = "@CreateArray(["your-collection-1","Collection-2"])" },
    Activities = new List<Activity>
    {
        new CopyActivity
        {
            Name = "CosmosDBCopyActivity",
                        Inputs = new List<DatasetReference>
                        {
                            new DatasetReference()
                            {
                                ReferenceName = datasetName //<your-source-datasetname>
                            }
                        },
                        Outputs = new List<DatasetReference>
                        {
                            new DatasetReference
                            {
                                ReferenceName = dataset2 //<Your-destination-datasetname>
                            }
                        },
            Source = new DocumentDbCollectionSource { },
            Sink = new DocumentDbCollectionSink { },
        }
    }
};

PipelineResource pipeline = new PipelineResource
{
    Activities = new List<Activity> { forEachActivity }
};
client.Pipelines.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, "YourPipelineName", pipeline);
```

You can use the below code to create the dataset for cosmosdb.

While creating a dataset for cosmos DB, In collection give the value as **`"@item()"`**

**Code:**

```
var containerDataset = new DatasetResource
{
    Properties = new CosmosDbSqlApiCollectionDataset
    {
        LinkedServiceName = new LinkedServiceReference { ReferenceName = "xxxxx" },
        CollectionName = "@item()"
    }
};
adfClient.Datasets.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, datasetName, containerDataset);
```

**Reference:**

- [CosmosDBSqlApiCollectionDataset Class (Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory.Models) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.datafactory.models.cosmosdbsqlapicollectiondataset?view=azure-dotnet-preview)
- [ForEachActivity.Items Property (Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.foreachactivity.items?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-management-datafactory-models-foreachactivity-items)